# How do I remove a contact from a group using the API?

Tags: api, groups

As part of an import process, I'm trying to remove contacts from a group. There is a `delete` call for the `GroupContact` entity but this has been deprecated in favour of `create` (which I find puzzling). A `getfields` call shows that a `CRM_Core_SelectValues::groupContactStatus` callback is available, but this takes no arguments and is for display purposes only as far as I can tell.

How do I use the `create` function to remove a specific contact from a group, or if that isn't possible, how do I use the API to remove a contact from a group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From using the API Explorer (**Support menu > Developer > API Explorer**) I can see that you can delete a GroupContact entity by specifying a GroupContact ID and a Group Contact Status of "Removed".

I don't think that makes a lot of sense - even for a non-standard API such as GroupContact, since a Group Contact Status of "Removed" is NOT the same as a deleted contact.

Note that my findings are at variance with [CRM-16878](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16878), which covers the same topic.

Comment: Hi Jon, I asked on #civicrm and Eileen gave me the same answer. Thanks for this!